# Cannot do proper method to delete max value of matrix.java

Tags: java

I ve just started my Java education, so this is one of my hometasks, I did most part of task, but struggling with last part. 
So the problem is that I really cannot do this method properly. I need to delete max value from matrix.
Main method looks like this

```
public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter size of matrix: ");
        int size = scanner.nextInt();
        int matrix[][] = new int[size][size];
        RandomedMatrix(matrix, size);
        matrix = RandomedMatrix(matrix, size);
        System.out.println("Matrix: ");
        printMatrix(matrix, size);
        matrixInIncreaseOrder(matrix, size);
        sumMatrixBetweenNegElem(matrix);
        DeleteMaxElem(matrix, size);
```

Method I need to do looks like this now

```
private static void DeleteMaxElem(int[][] matrix, int size) {
        boolean del = false;
        int size2 = size;
        matrix = Integer.MAX_VALUE(matrix);
        for (int j = matrix; j < size; j++) {
            del = true;
            for (int i = matrix; i < size2; i++)
                if (matrix[i][j] != 0) {
                    del = false;
                    break;
                }
            if (del) {
                for (int k = j; k < (size - 1); k++)
                    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
                        matrix[i][k] = matrix[i][k + 1];
                --j;
                --size;
            }
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            del = true;
            for (int i = 0; i < size2; i++)
                if (matrix[i][j] != 0) {
                    del = false;
                    break;
                }
            if (del) {
                for (int k = j; k < (size - 1); k++)
                    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
                        matrix[i][k] = matrix[i][k + 1];
                --j;
                --size;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Matrix without maximum value: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
                System.out.print(matrix[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please tell us your complete task so we may be able to help you.

Comment: What error are you getting? At first glance, `matrix = Integer.MAX_VALUE(matrix);` won't compile, you can't assign int to array of arrays of ints.

Comment: and `MAX_VALUE` is not a method, it is a field

Comment: I need to find highest element in a matrix and delete it, then print matrix without this element

Comment: What do you mean by "delete it"? You cannot just remove an element from a matrix since a matrix has a fixed size. Maybe you want to delete the row and column that contain this element (thus shrinking the matrix dimension)? Or maybe you want to replace the element by 0? These are very different things. Also, what should happen in case there are multiple elements of maximal value?

Comment: I need replace element by 0. All of them, like if its 4 I need to remove all 4 from matrix

Comment: Your first loop and nested loop should store the max value of the entire matrix into a variable, the second loop should compare this variable against each cell, and if true, set those cells to 0.

Comment: An alternative, is to store an array of index pairs on your first iteration (Add to list for matching max value, clear list on finding a higher max value) and iterate through that in your second loop to set matrix[i][k] = 0;